# Why is my site ssl not active but active in WordPress panel?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Hi I'm Mohammad Reza I wanted to know why ssl is not active when I visit to my site but it is active in my wordpress panel?
It's my site (not active ssl): https://topmoviex.ir/
This page is active ssl: [https://topmoviex.ir/پروفایل-کاربری/](https://topmoviex.ir/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C/)

Comment: it's active. You can close your question. Also, question is not meet to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first go to your wordpress admin panel -> setting -> general -> and change http to https

[image]

[image]

Go to the plufins and search for a plugin to force ssl 
[image]

Or use a CDN Service like CloudeFlare and use Flexible SSL